# Изменение атрибута PropertyOrder у наследников

Tags: c#, наследование, property, атрибуты

Здравствуйте. Есть один класс, у него свойство:

```
[PropertyOrder(1)]//номер в списке по идее должен разным у родителя и наследника
[DisplayName("Количество в попугаях")]
[Description("Количество в попугаях с округлением в меньшую сторону")]
[Category("3. Эксплуатационные")]
public int count { get; set; }
```

Возможно ли у наследников этого класса изменить атрибут PropertyOrder свойства count и/или добавить новый атрибут? Или же необходимо переопределять всё свойство?

Comment: Спасибо. Понял. Вопрос закрыт. (можно это как-то сделать "официально"?)

Comment: @LXA: А чего вы хотите добиться? Расскажите о своей задаче.

Comment: В общем, задача скорее рефакторинга, существует несколько классов, которые хотелось объединить. Но они имеют некоторые, в том числе незначительные, типа положения в меню свойств, отличия. Чтобы избежать потом "сделай, как было", хотелось и несколько уменьшить дублирование, и оставить то же самое визуальное поведение.

Comment: Я правильно понял, у предка выставлены все атрибуты, кроме "разнящегося", наследники реализуют этот атрибут (ну и, понятно, другие отличия)?

Comment: @LXA: ага, именно так.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! (Можете конвертануть коммент в ответ, чтобы было "отвечено", для пущей педантичности)

Comment: @LXA: Угу, сконвертировал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку экземпляр класса-наследника [является](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) экземпляром класса-предка, то и атрибут `count` обязан у них работать одинаково. Вы хотите нарушить [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), не делайте этого. Мне кажется, стоит исправить дизайн структуры классов так, чтобы этого не было нужно.

Возможно, вам стоит сделать класс-предок абстрактным, произвести от него *два* конкретных потомка, и атрибут `count` сделать также абстрактным.